# MySQL and LUA not triggering correctly or code incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, lua, fivem

I am struggling to trigger a server event succesfully on my FiveM server. Or maybe it gets triggered but the server event is incorrect. However I do not get any errors and I don't know what to fix...

**Server-side**

```
RegisterServerEvent('carwash:pay')
AddEventHandler('carwash:pay', function()
    local _source = source
    local price = 20
    local identifier = GetPlayerIdentifier(_source)
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT * FROM economy WHERE identifier = @identifier", {
    ['@identifier'] = identifier
    }, function(result)
        if result >= 20 then
    MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE economy SET cash = cash - @price WHERE identifier = @identifier',
    { ['@identifier'] = identifier, ['@price'] = price }
    )
        end
    end)
end)
```

**Client-Side**

```
TriggerServerEvent('carwash:pay')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still working on it or figured it out but for those who have the same problem, I'm gonna answer this.

The problem here is that you are comparing a whole table (SELECT * FROM economy...) to the number 20.

Besides, a "fetchAll" will allways output an array, so, in order to acces the column cash from the table economy, you need to use "result[1].cash".

Then, sometimes the "error" is not a syntaxe one, you need to put some "print()" here and there to understand where it stops, changes or just check if it works.

e.g. :

```
RegisterServerEvent('carwash:pay')
AddEventHandler('carwash:pay', function()
    local _source = source
    local price = 20
    local identifier = GetPlayerIdentifier(_source)
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll("SELECT * FROM economy WHERE identifier = @identifier", {['@identifier'] = identifier}, 
    function(result)

        -- CHECK WHAT IT RESULT 
        print(result)

        if result >= 20 then
        MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE economy SET cash = cash - @price WHERE  identifier = @identifier', { ['@identifier'] = identifier, ['@price'] = price })
        end
    end)
end)
```